# how to open Visual studio on the command line on mac

Tags: terminal, command

when i try this command to open Atom open - a atom,  it works perfectly, but when I try this command open -a code to open the visual studio it says code application not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `code .` in the directory you want to open the editor in